# How to show that $x-1$ and $x^2+x+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb R[x]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that $x-1$ and $x^2+x+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb R[x]?$

I can see that $x - 1$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ are nonzero and non-units (for any field $F$ the set of all units of $F[x]$ = $F-\{0\}$)?

*Added:* Actually I would like to show $f(x)|(x-1)(x^2+x+1)~\text{where }\deg f(x)\ge 1~\implies f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)~or~(x-1)~or~(x^2+x+1).$ Does showing $(x-1)~and~(x^2+x+1)$ irreducible help me anyhow?

Comment: irreducible = Not reducible

Comment: c is nonzero, nonunit and $c=ab\implies a~or~b$ is a unit

Comment: $\deg f(x)+\deg g(x)=1$

Comment: Your edit is wrong. $f(x)$ can be $\alpha$ or $\alpha(x-1)(x^2+x+1) $ or $\alpha(x-1)$ or $\alpha(x^2+x+1)$, where $\alpha$ is any unit of $F[x]$. You might say that that's obviously what you meant, but it's important to get these things right!

Comment: @TonyK: added the extra condition.

Comment: @TonyK: Why don't you post it as an answer? It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Still not right! You're not paying attention, user78452. Are you aware that, for instance, $3x-3$ divides $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ in $\mathbb R[x]$?

Answer (score 5):

For the first polynomial, you might want to see what would happen if you could express 
$x-1=p*q$, where p and q are polynomials with smaller degree. For the second, maybe check out the roots of the quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f\in F[x]$ with $F$ field. It is immediate to show that $f$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if it has no divisors of degree $k$ with $0<k<\deg (f)$ (just unfold the definition).

Now, from this carachterization it is obvious that $x-1$ is an irreducible polynomial (over any field indeed). About $g:=x^{2}+x+1$, suppose it is not irreducible; then there must be a polynomial $ax+b\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ ($a\neq 0$) such that $ax+b\mid g$, i.e $-b/a$ must be a root for $g$. But $g$ has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

1 is the only root of $X-1$, and it is not a root of $X^2+X+1$, so the GCD of both polynomials is 1. That's all there is to say :)